# Read Facebook Claims - Is this a good approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, claims-based-identity, owin

I'm trying to read FB claims after authenticating the user. This is my code so far:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    var externalIdentity = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    dynamic emailClaim = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(externalIdentity.Result.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Value);
    dynamic locationClaim = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(externalIdentity.Result.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:location").Value);
    dynamic genderClaim = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(externalIdentity.Result.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:gender").Value);
    dynamic firstNameClaim = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(externalIdentity.Result.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:first_name").Value);
    dynamic birthdateClaim = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(externalIdentity.Result.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:birthday").Value);

    var email = emailClaim.email;
    var city = locationClaim.name.ToString().Split(',')[0];
    var country = locationClaim.name.ToString().Split(',')[1];

    var gender = genderClaim.gender;
    var firstname = firstNameClaim.first_name;
    var birthdate = DateTime.ParseExact(birthdateClaim.birthday, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

As you can see, I'm converting FB claims into a dynamic object so I can later reference it easier.

Do you think this is a good approach? I'm planning to read the provider and apply strategy pattern to encapsulate this logic. Sounds good for you? Or should I refactor to something else?

Comment: could you please share more related code? I have set to use facebook options to have scope `user_birthday`, but the following line `dynamic birthdateClaim = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(externalIdentity.Result.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:birthday").Value);` fails because there is no appropriate claim in the collection

Comment: @Dmitry You have to add that to your scopes with this line:

 fbScopes.Scope.Add("user_birthday");

Comment: I did, in the `Startup.Auth.cs`:
`var fbOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions { AppId = "whatever", AppSecret = "whatever" };
fbOptions.Scope.Add("email");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");
fbOptions.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fbOptions);`
Still does not work

Comment: @Dmitry do you have an email where I can send you the working code?

Comment: yea, please send to `dmitrief@gmail.com`. I really appreciate your help!